# Perl's -d switch breaks <STDIN> reading from a form's POST

Tags: perl

Has anyone had the Perl -d switch break  reading from a form's POST?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -d
```

The following code worked fine on my windows WAMP setup, but when I moved it to my web host, `$ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'}` would show an appropriate size, but `$buff` would be empty. By removing the `-d` switch it worked.

```
   elsif ($ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} eq 'POST') {
            read(STDIN, $buff, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});
            #$buff = <STDIN>;
             @pairs = split(/&/, $buff);
             &write_to_log("pairs: @pairs buffer: $buff : len : $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'}");
```

It took me hours to figure out what was causing this, I hope it helps someone else. I just am curious if this is normal or something odd with my webhosts setup?

Comment: The `-d` switch was causing this. What did you think would happen when you put the `-d` switch in the shebang line?

Comment: Actually there’s one other option that belongs in this set and that’s -d. This option puts you into the Perl debugger. This is also a subject that’s too big for this article, but I recommend you look at “perldoc perldebug” or Richard Foley’s Perl Debugger Pocket Reference. [Source](https://www.perl.com/pub/2004/08/09/commandline.html/)

Comment: See: [perldebug](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug)

Comment: Putting the `-d` switch on your shebang line seems like a pretty bizarre thing to do, to be honest. What were you trying to achieve?

Comment: Also, why do you have code to extract parameters like this in your program? You'd be much better advised to use [CGI.pm](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI).

Comment: Also, using `&` on subroutine calls [hasn't been necessary since Perl 5 was released in 1994](https://perlhacks.com/2015/04/subroutines-and-ampersands/). Please don't do that.

Comment: The Perl debugger takes commands from STDIN. So it's not surprising it reads STDIN.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all first responders and your comments!

The -d is often  quickly testing a change on my site, and I have forgotten to remove the -d debug switch. Yes lazy, but that would describe me in a word. I usually use GET while testing my code, then change it to POST when I am done. So I had never really noticed the effect of not removing the -d. This time I switched to POST before I was totally done.

I thought cgi.pm (according to Wikipedia) was unmaintained and should be avoided. Even so, if a few lines of code will do what I need I choose not to use a module.

I always liked the & for subroutines. Just a personal preference.

**That makes sense. Since I am not using a debugger on my web host the STDIN from my POST would be going into a bit bucket.**

I am not condoning bad programming practices, just my bad programming practices :)